# Change pixel value in OpenCV.js

Tags: javascript, opencv

According to [OpenCV.js](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html) docs to modify a pixel value you can use 3 methods:

1. Direct data manipulation
2. `at()` family of methods
3. `ptr()` family of methods

Althougth the header of the section in the docs say "Accessing and Modifying pixel values" it provides examples for retrieving a value but not for modifying them. The problem is that while in C++ this code using the `at` or `ptr` methods works:

`mat.at<type>(row, col) = value;`

The equivalent in javascript is not valid and gives an `Invalid left hand side in assignment expression`:

`mat.floatAt(row, col)) = value;`

I could make it work using the direct data manipulation method with:

`mat.data[row * this.cols * this.channels() + col * this.channels()] = value;`

But this method does not operate in pixel values but in the underlaying array data structure where a pixel may span more than one array index, so is not valid for my use case.

**How can a pixel value at [row, col] position in a CvMat be modified using OpenCV.js?**

Answer (score 7):

I have been successful in setting single pixels of images (or matrices) with ucharPtr.

Instead of setting it like this:

```
img.ucharPtr(i, j) = 255
```

I set it like this:

```
img.ucharPtr(i, j)[0] = 255
```

Even if the image is black and white and only has one channel

If you want to set all 4 pixel values, you can do this:

```
src.ucharPtr(i, j)[0] = 255
src.ucharPtr(i, j)[1] = 255 
src.ucharPtr(i, j)[2] = 255 
src.ucharPtr(i, j)[3] = 0
```